# behavior of squeeze function in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am playing the squeeze function (matlab 2013b) and confused about it's behavior.

```
a(:,:,1)=[1 2 3];
a(:,:,2)=[4 5 6];
a(:,:,3)=[7 8 9];
a(:,:,4)=[10 11 12];
sa = squeeze(a);

b(:,:,1)=[1;2;3];
b(:,:,2)=[4;5;6];
b(:,:,3)=[7;8;9];
b(:,:,4)=[10;11;12];
sb=sqeeuze(b)
```

I would expect that sa to be 4*3 and sb to be 3*4, and sa being transpose(sb). Since each "layer" of a is a row vector, whereas each "layer" of b is a column vector. but, in fact sa is the same as sb.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `squeeze` just removes ones in `size()`.  So if `size(a)` is `[1 3 4]` you end up with `[3 4]` for `sa`. of course, this process involves reshaping the matrix. For example, second dim of `a` becomes first dim of `sa`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of squeeze is very simple, remove singleton dimensions. The size of a is `[1,3,4]`, removing singleton dimensions you get `[3,4]`. The size of b is `[3,1,4]`, squeezing you get `[3,4]`.

If squeeze does not what you want, take a look at `reshape` and `permute`